# Why to use using statement on DbTransaction in ADO.NET / C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactions, system.data

I understood the implicit rollback (that usually happens when exception happens and Dispose is called) is not guaranteed for all providers. However many examples uses:

```
using (DbTransactio txn = cnctn.BeginTransaction())
```

is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most plain answer there would be "because it implements `IDisposable`". Any type that implements `IDisposable`: it is your job to dispose it appropriately. In this case, with procedural code, the simplest way to do that would be via a `using` statement.

In this specific case, the answer would be: because in the event of error, you want the transaction rolled back rather than left to the GC. Personally I would probably tend to use `catch` to `Rollback`, but one should *hope* that the `Dispose()` already does that. I wouldn't rely on it myself, though, unless it was documented. For example:

```
using(var tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        // do stuff...
        tran.Commit();
    } catch {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Note that in the related case of `TransactionScope`, the "`Dispose()` without marking it completed" is the *expected* way of signalling a rollback:

```
using(var tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    // do stuff...
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. my point is that does Dispose do anything else than call Rollback (in most/all cases)? Is there a reason to call Dispose if one wants to have Rollback in catch clause? I think calling Rollback excplicitly is far better coding. So is Dispose necessary for already committed/rollbacked transaction?

Comment: @matti `Dispose()` is strongly advised simply because it is `IDisposable`. I would agree that *in this case* I'd prefer explicit `Rollback()`, as per my example. But that is in *addition* to `Dispose()`, not instead of.

Comment: thanks. i think that's good enough reason for me :D  but as I said I prefer explictit rollback. that's just little tricky cause if something goes wrong, the transaction is not active any more. So your code example throws an exception about rollback and original cause is missed. For example MSDN had an example where Rollback in catch clause was inside an additional catch-clause... Which is absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 5):

If you have code like this:

```
DbTransactio txn = cnctn.BeginTransaction();

// do something which throws an exception

txn.Commit();
```

the transaction wont be rolled back until the garbage collector decides to collect the transaction object (do note that it will only work if the class that implements `IDisposable` follows the [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=VS.9%29.aspx)).

You could of course do this:

```
DbTransaction txn = cnctn.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    // do something which throws an exception

    txn.Commit();
}
finally  
{
    txn.Dispose();
}
```

but that's not as readable as

```
using (var txn = cnctn.BeginTransaction())
{
    // do something which throws an exception

    txn.Commit();
}
```

Edit:

> I understood the implicit rollback (that usually happens when exception happens and Dispose is called) is not guaranteed for all providers.

I haven't seen a single provider which do not support it. Since [IDbTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbtransaction.aspx) do inherit `IDisposable` all implementations should use `Dispose()` to rollback the transaction.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i understand what using means, but why to call Dispose at all if all it does is that it calls rollback?

Comment: there is no need to explicitly call `Rollback` if you are using `using`. imho the code is cleaner to have a using block with a `Commit()` in it.